# Max<TSource,TResult> - Как получить максимальный элемент?

Tags: c#

У меня есть список (допустим, `List`) экземпляров `Video`:

```
class Video
{
    public Video(int r){
        resolution = r;
    }

    public int resolution;
}

var list = new List<Video>();


list.Add(new Video(0));
list.Add(new Video(100));
list.Add(new Video(50));
```

Не пойму, как я могу с помощью метода  [Max](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.max?view=netcore-2.2#System_Linq_Enumerable_Max__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__) с такой сигнатурой:

`Max<TSource,TResult>(IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource,TResult>)`

могу получить на выходе видео с максимальным значением resolution?

Я думал, что это делается просто:

```
Video video = list.Max(v => v.resolution);
```

Но компилятор пытается в итоге преобразовать v.resolution (тип `int`) к типу `Video`. Не понимаю, как я могу идиоматично получить объект из списка с максимальным resolution в этой ситуации (без ручного перебора каждого значения в цикле)?

Заранее спасибо

Comment: Если вы хотите использовать просто `.Max()`, то установите `MoreLINQ`, который имеет метод `.MaxBy()` (можете реализовать [сами](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/ec4bbd3c7ca61e3a98695aaa2afb23da001ee420/MoreLinq/MaxBy.cs)). Если вам надо стандартно получить объект, то отсортируйте для начала элементы (`.OrderBy()`) по нужному свойству и потом возьмите просто первое значение (`.First()` / `.FirstOrDefault()`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ,  благодарю. То, что нужно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам необходимо реализовать интерфейс `IComparable<Video>` у вашего класса Video и тогда можно применять метод `Max` к коллекции `IEnumerable<Video>`.

Максимальное значение из множества можно получить только в том случае, если на нем введено отношение порядка, т.е. правило по которому можно определить какой элемент больше другого. Вы тем куском кода, который вы указали, преобразовали множество **Video** в множество **int** и получили максимальный **int**.

Comment: Спасибо, я понял